# Viewport meta tag not working

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios

I am testing an app on iPhone. When it's in portrait, the resize is perfect. But when switching to landscape, it's zooming.

I have put 
`{meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"}` but it seems to be not working.

I have also tried `{meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0"}` but of no help.

Please help me !!!

Comment: You will need to post way more information, like code and what isn;t working or what is work but not as you expected.

Comment: Your question is not so clear. What you want?

Comment: have put {meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"} but it seems to be not working

I have also tried {meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0"} but of no help

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"></meta>
```

I think user-scaleable=0 there is the key !